# vscode python extension cant install from any source

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, vsix

Trying to install python extension for vscode but i always encounter an error.
by the way, python 3.10.9 is installed on my pc and works correctly

i tried installing it from the vscode editor but encounterd an error
i downloaded the vsix file using 2 different PCs but that too i always lebeled as corrupt
picture is below
any ideas please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z6S8.png)

Comment: Hi, did you check the log, and can you show it ?

Comment: thanks for trying to assist, i solve the issue by switching to a stronger internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a hours, i got the solution to my case.
for me, the internet connection was slow and caused interuptions in the installation.
I realise this when i got a stronger internet connection and the extension installed properly and without any suffering.